# Types 'int' and 'str' are unsupported as operands for +=

Tags: python, rhino3d

I am totally new to this and search did not help.

This works:

```
import rhinoscriptsyntax as rs

obj = rs.GetObject("Select a curve", rs.filter.curve)

if rs.IsCurve(obj):
    i=0
    while i < 100:
        rs.OffsetCurve( obj, [0,0,0], -i )
        i += 0.2
        rs.OffsetCurve( obj, [0,0,0], -i )
        i += 0.7
```

This does not:

```
import rhinoscriptsyntax as rs

a = raw_input("Please enter first number: ")
b = raw_input("Please enter second number: ")

obj = rs.GetObject("Select a curve", rs.filter.curve)

if rs.IsCurve(obj):
    i=0
    while i < 100:
        rs.OffsetCurve( obj, [0,0,0], -i )
        i += a
        rs.OffsetCurve( obj, [0,0,0], -i )
        i += b
```

With integers it's `i += int(a)`, but `a` and `b` must be decimals.

I have no clue. Help :)

Danke

Comment: Just use `input` instead of `raw_input`.

Comment: @CristiFati Only if this is Python 3.

Comment: Why not use decimal.decimal when they have to be decimal?

Comment: @chepner: *Python3* doesn't have it.

Comment: worked! that was easier than i expected. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To convert to float instead of int:

```
i += float(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try initializing the values for a and b to 0.0 so that python looks at them as decimals.